# Proper way to close/finish Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

My app starts up at Activity A which contains a ListView.  The ListView can have items added to it if the user hits "Add" button and goes to Activity B.

In Activity B they fill out some forms and hit "OK" button which takes them back to Activity A where the new item is added to the ListView.

I have a finish() method after going from B to A -- but NOT the other way around.

So if you hit back three times after adding three items.  It will just repeat the ListView (Activity A) over 3 times -- less one item that was added.

What is the best way in doing this?  I can't put a finish method on the "Add" Button (going from A to B) because if you are in Activity B, it will close the app instead of taking you back to A -- which I do not want. That is, if the user changes his mind and doesn't want to "Add new item" by hitting "OK" while in B.  Is a manual Back button the only answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start Activity B by using `startActivityForResult()` and finish activity B after filling the form.

**EDIT**

When you `startActivityForResult()`, you pass 2 parameters, namely `intent` and `requestcode`. After you are finished with the new activity(in your case Activity B) you use a function `setResult(RESULT_OK)` to signify that the operation in Activity B was successful and then you call `finish()`. After the call to `finish()` the Activity B will return to Activity A and will call `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`. The parameter `requestcode` helps in identifying which particular activity/request has returned.

Hope this explanation helps you.

Comment: Thank you, what would I use for the int in the second value of  "startActivityForResult(intent, int)"?

Comment: @KickingLettuce I have edited my answer with the explanation for `startActivityForResult(intent, int)`.

Comment: The second parameter of startActivityForResult is a request identifier. This is passed to onActivityResult when that gets called, so you know what activity is passing back a result (in situations where an activity could get results from many different activities). In your case, only calling startActivityForResult in one location, just using 1 will suffice.